# Learning about Maps interface in java, can you reference different values on the same key?

Tags: java, collections, dictionary, interface

I'm learning about the Maps interface in java, can you reference different values on the same key? My assignment is to build a dictionary program that reads in a novel text file as well as a dictionary. The novel is read in as a paragraph and later parsed into separate words/strings so that they can be searched for spelling in the dictionary. Our first task was to do this using the collections interface, now I have to use maps and reference the paragraphs (the value) with the misspelled word (key). If I have a misspelt word it only get referenced to a single paragraph and I am not sure how to reference it to multiple values.

```
public void spellCheck() {
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    for (String singleParagraph : book.wordCollection) {
        String[] arrayWords = singleParagraph.split("[^a-zA-Z_0-9']+");
        for (String word : arrayWords) {
            if (useOptionalDict) {
                if ((dictionary.wordCollection.contains(word) != true)
                        && (word.isEmpty() != true)
                        && (optionalDictionary.wordCollection
                                .contains(word) != true)) {
                    misspelledWord.put(word, singleParagraph);
                }// end if
            }// end if
            else {
                if ((dictionary.wordCollection.contains(word) != true)
                        && (word.isEmpty() != true)) {
                    misspelledWord.put(word, singleParagraph);
                }// end if
            }// end else
        }// end enhanced for
    }// end enhanced for loop
    double elapseTime = (double) (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime) / 1000.0;
    System.out
            .printf("\nTotal time to spell check %s: %f\nTotal mispelled words: %d\n",
                    book.getFileName(), elapseTime, misspelledWord.size());
}// end spellCheck()
```

Comment: Could you use a `Map` object in which the values are `Set` objects?

Comment: Make the value a list of the desired type. Then add to it as you wish.

Comment: In this case, there are a few useful tricks, like storing collections as the map values or (my preference) using Guava's `Multimap`, but most of this would have been answered by reading [the Javadoc for `Map`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html).

Answer (score 2):

Its not possible to map multiple values to the same key in Java. However you can create a custom map to do so.

```
 Map<K, List<V>> map = new HashMap <K, ArrayList<V>>:
 where K => key type
 v => Value type
```

Now you can code as follows :

Insert : First Check if the Key is present in the Map. IF present then extract the corresponding List for that Key and add the element to the List. Or else you need to initialize a new ArrayList & then add the value to it & then insert ArrayList into the Map.

As you can observe this is a lot of boiler plate code that would be repeated in case you need such a Data structure again in your coding career. So smart people have developer libraries that you can use for mapping multiple values to a single key. Multimap is such a data structure. You can look into MultiMap from Google Guava library [Link](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained)

Comment: It is possible if you make a `Collection` the value.

Comment: @aliteralmind Thanks a lot for bringing that up...I had completely missed it

Comment: How do I add the referenced string to the collection in the map then? This stuff is frustrating.